# javascript - Origin http://127.0.0.1 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, picasa

I'm making a simple gallery that takes the photos from a picasa account with html + javascript.

First, gets the list of albums and then, for each album, gets the list of photos. The first query works fine, but the others returns this error in the Browser (Chrome):

> GET https://picasaweb.google.com/data/entry/base/user/114476218463019618611/albumid/5750459375839674337?alt=json&hl=en_US 404 (Not Found) jquery.js:8240
>   XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://picasaweb.google.com/data/entry/base/user/114476218463019618611/albumid/5750459375839674337?alt=json&hl=en_US. Origin file:// is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

This is the code:

```
           var json_Album_URI = "https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/base/"
                + "user/"       +   username
                + "?alt="       +   "json"
                + "&kind="      +   "album"
                + "&hl="        +   "en_US"
                + "&fields="    +   "entry(media:group,id)"
                + "&thumbsize=" +   104
                + "&authkey="   +   authkey;

            $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: json_Album_URI,
                    success : function(resp) {
                            albums = resp.feed.entry;
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    async: false
            });
            for (var id in albums) {
                    var album = albums[id];
                    var album_ID = album.id.$t.split('/')[9].split('?')[0];
                    var json_Photo_URI = "https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/base/"
                            + "user/"       +   username
                            + "/albumid/"   +   album_ID
                            + "?alt="       +   "json"
                            + "&kind="      +   "photo"
                            + "&hl="        +   "en_US"
                            + "&fields="    +   "entry(media:group)"
                            + "&thumbsize=" +   104
                            + "&authkey="   +   authkey;
                    //this is the ajax call that fails
                    $.ajax( {
                            type: 'GET',
                            url: json_Photo_URI,
                            success: function(photos) {
                                    console.log(photos);
                            },
                            dataType: "json",
                            async: false,
                    });
            }
```

Thanks.

EDIT:

I notica that if I remove the line:

```
                            + "/albumid/"   +   album_ID
```

works (of course, without the expected response).

Comment: try JSONP instead of json for cross domain ajax call

Comment: Here's a JSONP version that works on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XsfNE/. Not sure if this implies that it works locally, though. (I used a random ID found on the Internet because your URL was a 404.)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) is to blame. Picasa's header responses differ between those two requests. It succeeds when they include `access-control-allow-origin:*`.

Picasa includes it in: https://picasaweb.google.com/data/entry/base/user/114476218463019618611?alt=json&hl=en_US

But not in: https://picasaweb.google.com/data/entry/base/user/114476218463019618611/albumid/5750459375839674337?alt=json&hl=en_US